# How to manage sudoers file when dealing with multiple similar rules?

Tags: linux, sudoers, maintenance

When I add a rule in the sudoers file, how can I know that I will not override and invalidate it in another future rule addition? I don't want to eye-inspect the sudoers file and preferably things are done automatically and in batch, e.g., using Ansible.

Let's say there's a systemd timer that runs some sudo commands and so needs `...NOPASSWD:/path/to/certain/program` but actually, in order not to prevent the user from running other sudo commands, its rule will be like this: `...PASSWD:ALL, NOPASSWD:/path/to/certain/program`, but the problem now is, next time if I don't pay attention to this line and add a new similar rule for program2, the previous rule will be overriden... .

A solution I can think of myself is "creating a new user per every new such scenario". E.g. `prog1user` for the first one and then in the future, adding a new (sudoer) user `prog2user` for the second one. Each with their own granular and specific NOPASSWD permissions. But stil adding new users for each future addition sounds painful to manage.

Is there a less-painful more-maintainable approach of managing the sudoers file when dealing with multiple similar rules?

Comment: Why do you think you need an explicit `PASSWD:ALL`? Just add a `NOPASSWD:/path/to/specific/utility` for the user(s) who need to run this specific utility with root privileges without supplying a password.

Comment: @tripleee I was under the impression that only a single rule can be specified for each user, but re-reading the manual it seems that having multiple sudoers rules per user is ok and will be applied based on order. Thank you.

Comment: Don't alter `/etc/sudoers`, it'll be rewritten during package update. Instead drop your customizations as files into `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory.